# Label background color gwt

Tags: gwt, label, background-color

I need to implement a background in a Label, and also, probably just fill half of it with one color and the another half with another. Whats the best way of achieving it?! Using CSS?! Or is there another easier way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

This is what CSS is used for.

```
Label label = new Label("your text");
label.setStyleName("myStyle");
```

And in your .css file:

```
.myStyle {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Or if you're using UIBinder:

```
<ui:style>
  .myStyle {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <g:Label styleName="{style.myStyle}">Your text</g:Label>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

The benefit of the UIBinder approach is that your style is in the same file as the Label and the CSS name will be obfuscated as well.